# Configuring CurrentCulture and CurrentUICulture with different parameters

Tags: c#, currentculture, currentuiculture

I am using c#.net3.5 and I want to change currentculture setting's decimal seperator from comma to dot, but at the same time I want user can use commas in numericupdown controlles as decimal seperator.
So I tried to change my culture setting as below

```
CultureInfo newUIculture = new CultureInfo("tr-TR");
newUIculture.NumberFormat.CurrencyDecimalSeparator = ",";
newUIculture.NumberFormat.CurrencyGroupSeparator = ".";
newUIculture.NumberFormat.NumberDecimalSeparator = ",";
newUIculture.NumberFormat.NumberGroupSeparator = ".";
newUIculture.NumberFormat.PercentDecimalSeparator = ",";
newUIculture.NumberFormat.PercentGroupSeparator = ".";
//Application.CurrentUICulture = newUIculture;//this line giving error.
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = newUIculture;//this line doesn't work

CultureInfo newCulture = new CultureInfo("tr-TR");
newCulture.NumberFormat.CurrencyDecimalSeparator = ".";
newCulture.NumberFormat.CurrencyGroupSeparator = "";
newCulture.NumberFormat.NumberDecimalSeparator = ".";
newCulture.NumberFormat.NumberGroupSeparator = "";
newCulture.NumberFormat.PercentDecimalSeparator = ".";
newCulture.NumberFormat.PercentGroupSeparator = "";
Application.CurrentCulture = newCulture;//this one work fine
```

current culture settings work fine but currentUIculture setting doesn't work as I assigned parameters. how can I configure both settings with parameters I give?

Answer (score 0):

CurrentUICulture is used to select which resource files are loaded.  CurrentCulture determines the result of culture-dependent functions such as formatting dates and numbers.  So the behavior you're seeing is expecte: you should be using CurrentCulture.

Comment: because of "UI" I thought maybe its connected with user interface.. I also think that I am doing something wrong. my aim is to change currentculture setting's decimal separator from comma to dot, but at the same time I want user can use commas in numericupdown controllers as decimal separator. is it possible with CurrentCulture?

Answer (score 0):

Peeking at `System.Windows.Forms.Application.CurrentCulture`, it's just a thin wrapper around `Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture`, and there's no such thing as `System.Windows.Forms.Application.CurrentUICulture`, which would explain why your commented-out line is throwing errors for you.

If by "doesn't work", you mean "doesn't change the decimal separator like I want it to", then you've already answered your own question: `CurrentCulture` is the thing that controls that, not `CurrentUICulture`.  There's a reason those are spelled differently.